# php read csv data as a string

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

Is there a function in php that lets you read a csv and return a string as it is.
I am aware of functions like `fgetcsv` etc that reads the csv and returns an array. But I was wondering if there is a way to get the full string as it is.

Comment: If you mean you want to read *each line* as a string, you can use `file()` ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php))

Comment: @PaulCrovella thanks. didn't know it was such easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://absoluteUrl');
```

or

```
$data = file_get_contents('local url');
```

Instead, to obtain an array of csv's lines use the [file](http://php.net/file) function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the file function:

```
$file = file("somefile.csv")
```

The you have every line in the variable file:

```
$file[0] = Firstline, aso.
```